# How safe is SymPy's sympify(<string>).evalf()?

Tags: python, eval, string-parsing

We know Python's `eval()` is evil

http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

and threads throughout StackOverflow suggest to use SymPy's `evalf()`.

As a Python newbie, I can't really convince myself that `evalf()` is safe as I lack the skills. Can anyone elaborate on what `evalf()` does (different)?

Comment: There are no suggestions to use `evalf` instead of `eval` as they have nothing in common. There are suggestions to use `sympify` instead of `eval`, but (from a security standpoint) they are misguided as these to are basically the same.

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing common between python `eval` and sympy `evalf` (the latter is for calculating the numeric value of sympy expression trees and it has **nothing** to do with parsing, while `eval` is all about parsing a string and evaluating it as if it is code).

On the other hand, `sympify` is just as dangerous as `eval`, because it actually uses `eval`.

There are two basic modes in which `sympify` is used and probably it is a bad idea that they got mixed in the same function:

- `sympify(some_object)` would return a representation of the object more suited for use in a CAS, like transforming `int(1)` into `sympy.Integer(1)`
- `sympify("some_text")` would parse the text almost directly through `eval` (search for the import from `sympy.parsing` present in `sympify` and follow it). It is safer as there are some constraints but it is **not safe**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate on the second basic mode, `sympify("some text")`, and how this could be exploited maliciously? For example, does [Ned Batchelder's eval dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) example work in SymPy? EG calling `f = sympy.sympify('__import__("os")')` does not give me a callable object.

Comment: OK, I was able to get access to `subprocess.Popen` using sympify and run a system command, EG `f = sympy.sympify("""[].__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()[158]('ls')""")` listed my directory contents. From there is just a simple step to `rm -rf \`. Well done [@Krastanov](http://stackoverflow.com/users/669329/krastanov) you have proven that sympy is **not** safe! Sympy is dangerous.