# How to evaluate a mathematical expression string the user passed to the program in python?

Tags: python, math

I wanted to write a program where the user can pass in the mathematical expression that they want to evaluate as a string.

So for instance, if the user enters a formula and other necessary arguments as string

```py
sin(x**2)/x, 0, pi/2
```

and I want to process that as an integral with the help from `math` of `sympy`, how shall I do it? I know how the package `sympy` can process mathematical expressions, but I don't know how to do it when the expression is a string.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you can't find a package which does everything you need, then for a general solution you should research how to build a simple parser in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - From string to sympy expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33606667/4996248)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the [sympify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.sympify.sympify) function.

You can also use the `split()` function to split the string the user types into an array, in order to get the other necessary arguments you mention needing.

For example:

```
from sympy import sympify
def evaluate(x, args[]):
    # do stuff
    return answer
in = input("Enter your expression: ")
x = in.split(",")
print(evaluate(x[0], [x[1], x[2], ...]))
```

EDIT: Just realized I forgot to describe how to use sympify, which is probably the most important thing with this question. Here is a simple example that should get across how to use it:

```py
x = sympify("x**2")
```

Comment: Thank you! Although I didn't eventually use this method, but the problem was solved nevertheless.

Comment: `sympy` uses `eval` under-the-hood, so it is not safe to use with user-supplied input. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10805