# Convert string of a named expression in sympy to the expression itself

Tags: python, expression, sympy

**Description of the practical problem**:

I have defined many expression using `sympy`, as in

```
import sympy as sp
a, b = sp.symbols('a,b', real=True, positive=True)
Xcharles_YclassA_Zregion1 = 1.01 * a**1.01 * b**0.99
Xbob_YclassA_Zregion1 = 1.009999 * a**1.01 * b**0.99
Xbob_YclassA_Zregion2 = 1.009999 * a**1.01 * b**0.99000000001
...
```

So I have used the names of the expressions to describe options (e.g., `charles`, `bob`) within categories (e.g., `X`).

Now I want a function that takes two strings (e.g., `'Xcharles_YclassA_Zregion1'` and `'Xbob_YclassA_Zregion1'`) and returns its simplified ratio (in this example, `1.00000099009999`), so I can quickly check "how different" they are, in terms of result, not in terms of how they are written.
E.g., `2*a` and `a*2` are the same for my objective.

**How can I achieve this?**

**Notes**:

1. The expressions in the example are hardcoded for the sake of simplicity. But in my actual case they come from a sequence of many other expressions and operations.
2. Not all combinations of options for all categories would exist. E.g., `Xcharles_YclassA_Zregion2` may not exist. Actually, if I were to write a table for existing expression names, it would be sparsely filled.
3. I guess rewriting my code using `dict` to store the table *might* solve my problem. But I would have to modify a lot of code for that.
4. Besides the practical aspects of my objective, I don't know if there is any formal difference between `Symbol` (which is a specific class) and *expression*. From the sources I read (e.g., [this](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/manipulation.html)) I did not arrive to a conclusion. This understanding may help in solving the question.

---

**TL;DR - What I tried**

I aimed at something like

```
def verify_ratio(vstr1, vstr2):
    """Compare the result of two different computations of the same quantity"""
    ratio = sp.N(sp.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(vstr1)) / sp.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(vstr2)
    print(vstr1 + ' / ' + vstr2, '=', sp.N(ratio))
    return
```

This did not work.
Code below shows why

```
import sympy as sp
a, b = sp.symbols('a,b', real=True, positive=True)
expr2 = 1.01 * a**1.01 * b**0.99
print(type(expr2), '->', expr2)
    
expr2b = sp.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr('expr2')
print(type(expr2b), '->', expr2b)

expr2c = sp.N(sp.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr('expr2'))
print(type(expr2c), '->', expr2c)
#print(sp.N(sp.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr('expr2')))

expr2d = sp.sympify('expr2')
print(type(expr2d), '->', expr2d)
```

with output

```
<class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'> -> 1.01*a**1.01*b**0.99
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'> -> expr2
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'> -> expr2
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'> -> expr2
```

I need something that takes the string `'expr2'` and returns the expression `1.01 * a**1.01 * b**0.99`.

---

None of my attempts achieved the objective.
Questions or links which did not help (at least for me):

1. [From string to sympy expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606667/from-string-to-sympy-expression)
2. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/basic_operations.html
3. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html
4. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.sympify.sympify
5. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/manipulation.html

Comment: I think you're trying to blur the line between python names, like `expr2`, and the variables within sympy expressions, like `a` and `b` in your example. Don't think that's a good design intent...

Comment: @MarcusMüller - I heavily edited the OP, based on your comment.
I have a practical objective. If that implies "blurring the line...", I am not sure.
If that can be done, I would be glad to hear how.
If that has associated risks/non-working cases/etc. (is that what you mean by not "a good design intent"? or what would that be?), I would also like to know them. Perhaps they are removed enough from my uses so I don't care.
If there are good alternatives, I also welcome them; I would try rewriting as little code as possible, contingent upon other considerations.

Comment: Put your expressions into a data structure like a dict rather than loads of global variables.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin you could post `eval` as an answer. It works.

Answer (score 1):

If, when parsing, you want to use the expression that has been mapped to a variable you have to pass the dictionary that python uses to keep track of those mappings, i.e. `locals()`

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> from sympy import sympify, parse_expr
>>> y = x + 2
>>> sympify('y')
y
>>> sympify('y', locals=locals())
x + 2
>>> parse_expr('y', local_dict=locals())
x + 2
```

Comment: This worked. Of course, given I use `parse_expr` within my function `verify_ratio`, I have to pass `locals()` as another of its parameters.
This is not very convenient, but not a no go either.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Oscar Benjamin from the Sympy Google group, `eval` does the job

```
def verify_ratio(vstr1, vstr2):
    """Compare the result of two different computations of the same quantity"""
    print(vstr1 + ' / ' + vstr2, '=', eval(vstr1 + ' / ' + vstr2))
    return
```

What shows this would work is

```
>>> import sys
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> a, b = sp.symbols('a,b', real=True, positive=True)
>>> a is eval('a')
True
```

In my case, all expressions and symbols I am using in `vstr1` and `vstr2` are global.
If nesting within other functions, I might need to pass further parameters to `verify_ratio`, as in the solution by smichr.

Comment: I would like to clarify that I actually suggested that using `eval` is not a good approach: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/discussions/24483

Comment: @OscarBenjamin - I didn't know the response was also in GitHub.
Would you mind clarifying what are the negative aspects of `eval`? Thanks!